# How to setup Linked Server with ODBC DSN for a 32-bit Firebird environment using the 64-bit MSSQL Provider

Tags: sql-server, odbc, firebird, firebird2.1

I am trying to make a Link Server to my running Firebird instance on SSMS however I am encountering the following error when I click "OK":

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL"
> for linked server "FIREBIRD". OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked
> server "FIREBIRD" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
> The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver
> and Application". (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Here is how I filled up the Link Server wizard and my DSN:
[image]

[image]

My Firebird version is `2.1.5.18497` at 32-bit, and the Firebird ODBC is at `2.0.5.156` at 32-bit.

The SQL Server I'm currently running on is `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)`

I am not using the latest Firebird version since there are incompatibilities on the ODS version of my .FDB file, and it can only be understood by the current Firebird version I have. I tried changing the Firebird ODBC driver to 64-bit but I am getting an error:

> Unable to connect to data source: library 'gds32.dll' failed to load

^ this is the error when testing the Firebird database connection to my .FDB file inside my DSN configuration if I used the 64-bit version of the Firebird ODBC driver.

I am thinking this happens because of the different bitness of providers on the MSSQL instance and the Firebird ODBC Driver. If this is the case, is it still possible to make a link server with my current Firebird and MSSQL setup? If not, is it still possible to upgrade the .FDB database to make the ODS version compatible to the newest version of Firebird so I can install the 64-bit version of it?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: SQL Server is a 64-bit applicationbut it appears (based on your screenshots) you've only installed the 32-bit driver which SQL Server won't be able to use. You need to install the 64 bit driver.

Comment: As side note, why have you not updated your SQL Server install in 4 years? There have been *many* security and bug fixes in that time.

Comment: Yes that's correct. Latest versions such as 2019 and so on is only available in 64-bit. But if I installed something like MSSQL 2014 32-bit, it won't let me because I am using a 64-bit server.

Comment: Again, you need to install the 64-bit Firebird Driver. A 64-bit application needs 64-bit drivers. Your screenshots imply you've (only) installed the 32-bit driver, which is the wrong "bitness".

Comment: @Thom A, it's because I need to stick on the current environment setup of my application. Upgrading to a new version isn't as simple to my current setup for the time being.

Comment: We're not talking about your application, we're talking about the driver.

Comment: You should be able to simultaneously have the 32 bit and 64 bit drivers installed on the same system. Applications (and SQL Server) should only use the drivers for the same architecture as themselves.

Comment: > Again, you need to install the 64-bit Firebird Driver. A 64-bit application needs 64-bit drivers. Your screenshots imply you've (only) installed the 32-bit driver, which is the wrong "bitness".

@Thom A, yes, I only have a 32-bit driver and I learned that it doesn't work because I am using a 64-bit SQL Server with a 64-bit provider. Which makes my 2nd question to my post if it's not possible.

Comment: Why won't you install the 64-bit driver..? If you refuse to install the 64-bit Firebird driver then you either need to downgrade to an older version of SQL Server (which will likely be (imminently) unsupported) and install the 32-bit version or find a different 64-bit driver you can use to connect to Firebird.

Comment: Because I am getting an error: Unable to connect to data source: library 'gds32.dll' failed to load

Comment: *"Unable to connect to data source: library 'gds32.dll' failed to load"* That doesn't sound like an installation error.

Comment: That happens if I test the connection when setting up DSN with a 64-bit driver

Comment: Now with 32-bit version of the driver, it works properly and my DSN is able to connect to my .FDB just fine.

Comment: Seems we have an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) here. What you've asked is how to set up the linked server, but what you *really* need to ask if how to set up an ODBC DSN for a 32-bit Firebird environment using the 64-bit driver.

Comment: There, changed the title to the one you suggested

Comment: According to my Google-Fu, the error *"library 'gds32.dll' failed to load"* means you have the wrong bitness installed for the application you're using. So perhaps you haven't installed the 64-bit driver? Have you checked the DLL file is in system32?

Comment: Again, @Thomas A, I already tried that with a 64-bit driver and I am getting library 'gds32.dll' failed to load. I already knew that it's because of 32-bit driver is not compatible with the 64-bit driver MSSQL has.

Comment: I googled a lot before I resorted asking this question alright?

Comment: Before you googled a lot did you read the Firebase quickstart guides where they recommend combing your system for gds32.dll and fbclient.dll files leftover from previous installations and removing them so that they don't interfere with new ones?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning this is not Firebase, this is Firebird

Comment: A typo, yes, but the **Firebird** quickstart guides do have that advice. Also, the Firebird v2.1 series reached end-of-life back in 2014... do you think it's time to upgrade yet?

Comment: Just a thought, can you just copy data manually from your old firebird db to a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of hardware architecture limitations **64 bits processes cannot load 32 bits libraries and vice versa**. So if you want to use Firebird from 64 bits MS SQL server you must have 64 bits Firebird client and 64 bits Firebird ODBC driver installed.

Note that **32 bits and 64 bits versions of these libraries can co-exist in system** so you can  install 32 bits versions as well if you need them for any other application.

You must set "fbclient.dll" as a client library name in ODBC settings.

Also it doesn't matter what bitness of Firebird server is. Only bitness of Firebird client library must match bitness of the application (MS SQL server in this case). Firebird client should be installed into system folder using "`instclient i f`" command from appropriate **ZIP package** from https://firebirdsql.org/en/server-packages/.

Firebird allows quite big difference between client and server versions, but still it is better to match them up to minor version. For third number - higher is better. I.e. 2.1.9 is better than 2.1.5.

Comment: Yes. I tried creating the DSN via a 64-bit Firebird ODBC driver and I am getting an error 

"Unable to connect to data source: library 'gds32.dll' failed to load" when testing the connection of my .FDB to my DSN. The reason being is that my Firebird is running in 32-bits. Which is the the only available bit on the version I am using.

Comment: Now if I connect using the latest version of Firebird, it won't work because the ODS is not compatible and can only be understood by Firebird 2.1.5

Comment: @jdistro07 I've added line about server bitness to the answer.

Comment: Where can I find this "Firebird client library"? Do you have any references you could give me?

Comment: I saw the link. Apparently I need to avoid those versions. There's an incompatibility of ODS version with an .FDB from v2.1.5 to the newest version on that page.

Comment: And v2.1.5 only has 32-bits. No 64-bit

Comment: @jdistro07 Look closer at "discontinued version" link: https://firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5/
And you don't need to install **server**. Install **client only**.

Comment: This works! Thanks for thoroughly explaining.